# Is there a tool which can view Bayer Pattern GBGR raw data picture

Tags: image-processing, camera, rgb, mosaic, raw-data

I know there are some tools such as vooya to view RGB pattern raw data picture.

Is there any tool that can view Bayer Pattern GBGR raw picture directly?

Answer (score 1):

If it is still relevant, give this one a shot - 
http://www.irfanview.com/